# Error al usuar ngModel

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Estoy empezando a usar Angular, pero al hacer un ejercicio me esta mandado un error en Consola.

> Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Archivo html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          {{titulo}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" nombre="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" [(ngModel)]="cuadroNombre">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" nombre="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" [(ngModel)]="cuadroApellido">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="cargo">Cargo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" nombre="cargo" id="cargo" placeholder="Cargo" [(ngModel)]="cuadroCargo">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="salario">Salario</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" nombre="salario" id="salario" placeholder="Salario" [(ngModel)]="cuadroSalario">
              </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="agregarEmpleado()">Guardar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class=" col-sm-8">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
            <th scope="col">Cargo</th>
            <th scope="col">Salario</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let empleado of empleados; let i = index">
            <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
            <td>{{empleado.nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{empleado.apellido}}</td>
            <td>{{empleado.cargo}}</td>
            <td>{{empleado.salario}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Archivo component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Empleado } from './empleado.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  titulo = 'Listado de Empleados';

  cuadroNombre:string="";
  cuadroApellido:string="";
  cuadroCargo:string="";
  cuadroSalario:number=0;

  empleados:Empleado[] = [
    new Empleado("Javier", "Ferruzca", "Maestro", 200),
    new Empleado("Juana", "Rojas", "Ama de casa", 1000),
    new Empleado("Ignacio", "Ferrucca", "Mecanico", 2400),
    new Empleado("Armando", "Ferrusca", "Albañil", 2300),
    new Empleado("Juan", "Ferrusca", "Cajero", 2200)
  ];

  agregarEmpleado(){
    let miEmpleado = new Empleado(this.cuadroNombre, this.cuadroApellido, this.cuadroCargo, this.cuadroSalario);
    console.log(miEmpleado);
    // this.empleados.push(miEmpleado);
  }

  
  
}
```

En el curso que estoy siguiendo no marca error, pero a mi si me esta mandado esos errores.

Espero que me puedan apoyar dándome lluvia de ideas de como puedo solucionar dicho error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo depende de las version que tengas en las dependencias en el ejemplo que estas viendo o curso, quizás es una versión anterior, el erro te esta informando como lo puedes solucionar [image: Error imagen]

resuelve de la siguiente manera donde veas los inputs

Actual

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" nombre="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" [(ngModel)]="cuadroNombre">
```

Solucionado

Solución 1

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" nombre="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" [(ngModel)]="cuadroNombre" name="nombre">
```

Solución 2

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" nombre="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" [(ngModel)]="cuadroNombre" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Puedes leer esta documentación
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9230#issuecomment-228116474

Elegir una solución o la otra depende de tu implementación, con name esto queda en el FormGroup, con el standalone no se agregara al FormGroup